# scala 2.10 how to convert a string to number before sum

Tags: scala

I work with Spark 1.6 and scala 2.10.

I have the following dataframe

```
scala> df
res24: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string, count: string]
```

I want to execute the instruction

```
df.groupBy("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME")
.sum("count")
.withColumnRenamed("sum(count)","destination_total")
.sort(desc("destination_total"))
.limit(5)
.collect(5)
```

How can I convert the column count to integer to do  sum("count")?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following before you do the `groupBy` and `sum`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("count", $"count".cast(IntegerType))
```